# QuerySnapshot.docChanges has been changed from a property into a method

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting this message:

> QuerySnapshot.docChanges has been changed from a property into a method, so usages like "querySnapshot.docChanges" should become "querySnapshot.docChanges()"

I am using "firebase": "^5.3.0"

In my package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per the [version 5 release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore_28):

> QuerySnapshot.docChanges() is now a method that optionally takes an 
>   includeMetadataChanges option. By default, even when listening to a
>   query with {  includeMetadataChanges:true }, metadata-only document
>   changes are suppressed in  docChanges()

Usually Google deprecates things before removing them, so you get a warning instead of a break.

If you're not using this property explicitly in your code, make sure all libraries that depend on it (@angular/fire, etc) are all up to date.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything I can do about this? What would you suggest?

Comment: I'd make sure all dependent libraries are up to date and see if you're using this anywhere explicitly in your code so you can update it yourself.